# Border-bottom on headings with line-height / padding issues

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue that I hope someone will be able to help me out with.

I have and h2 element that i have given a width, so that long headlines break into two lines. I then want to add a border-bottom to the text, not the block element, and so i have wrapped the text inside the h2 element in a span that i apply the border to. Like this:

```
<h2><span>My headline that breaks into two lines</span><h2>
```

My css is like this:

```
h2 {
    width: 455px;
    height:170px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 67px;
    line-height: 90px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}

h2 span {
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Everything about works fine, EXCEPT i can't get my border to get any closer to the text. No matter what values i put in line-height and padding, the border seems to be stuck about the 30px below the text. Does anyone have any clever thoughts as to what I can do? I feel like I have tried every combination possible.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

html :

```
<div class="demo">
    <h2>
      <span>My headline that breaks into two lines</span>
    </h2>
  </div>
```

css:

```
.demo {
    width: 455px;
    height:170px;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 { 
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    display : inline;
    line-height: 90px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}

h2 > span {
  font-size: 67px;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

demo http://codepen.io/gauravsam/pen/PZQwNz

Answer (score 0):

add padding-bottom:10px;    [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wfCKA)

```
h2 {
    width: 455px;
    height:170px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 67px;
    line-height: 90px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}

h2 span {
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
    padding-bottom:10px;/*add this*/
}
```

Comment: I AM using a border, and not text-decoration. With text-decoration the underline is too close to the text, with border the line is too far away...

Comment: add padding-bottom: 5px;

Comment: You are really not reading the question. I want to make the spacing SMALLER not bigger.

Comment: ng that how you set the line should distance themselves from the text

Comment: I'm sorry @Alex Wilson but you are not any help at all, if you don't read my question all the way through before trying to answer it.

Comment: Well if it is less text-decoration: underline; easy to use border-bottom line is drawn at the bottom of the letter y

Comment: I read your question and understand what you want on this and suggest to your answers as solutions to your question, sorry that did not help

Answer (score 0):

in my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mofeenster/ccvzv/3/) you will see that by making line-height on the h2 relative, the span rests just under the descender (e.g. the letter y), is the border now closer to the baseline than you had it?

```
h2 {
    text-align: left;
    width: 400px;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: inherit;
}

span {
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Hi Morgan, no I'm afraid this doesn't change anything for me. Isn't it possible to have the border-bottom be above the descender ?

Comment: Hi Alxvo, it doesn't make sense as the border has to wrap with the text. And you have to take into account the line-height of the text. I will put my neck out here and say no.